# ColoredPrintf in recent googletest

Tags: c++, googletest

I was using rather obsolete version of GoogleTest and have used hack for custom printing, found here: [How to send custom message in Google C++ Testing Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491675/how-to-send-custom-message-in-google-c-testing-framework/29155677)

My sources contain the following code from the link above

```
namespace testing
{
 namespace internal
 {
  enum GTestColor {
      COLOR_DEFAULT,
      COLOR_RED,
      COLOR_GREEN,
      COLOR_YELLOW
  };

  extern void ColoredPrintf(GTestColor color, const char* fmt, ...);
 }
}
#define PRINTF(...)  do { testing::internal::ColoredPrintf(testing::internal::COLOR_GREEN, "[          ] "); testing::internal::ColoredPrintf(testing::internal::COLOR_YELLOW, __VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

I have updated sources of GoogleTest in my project to master version and now I have link errors saying that ColoredPrintf is not defined.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl testing::internal::ColoredPrintf(enum testing::internal::`anonymous namespace'::GTestColor,char const *,...)" (?ColoredPrintf@internal@testing@@YAXW4GTestColor@?A0x313d419f@12@PEBDZZ) referenced in function
```

Studying fresh `gtest.cc` shows that they have changed `GTestColor` to enum class and put it into an anonymous namespace inside the namespace `testing::internal`:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L3138

I've changed the snippet in my sources to:

```
namespace testing {
    namespace internal
    {
        enum class GTestColor { kDefault, kRed, kGreen, kYellow };

        extern void ColoredPrintf(GTestColor color, const char* fmt, ...);
    }
}
```

And as a quick fix I have removed `namespace { ... }` around `GTestColor` in `gtest.cc`.

The question: is it possible to avoid editing `gtest.cc` and still have access to their function?

Comment: I've submitted FR https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/4185 to have this addressed somehow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access members in an anonymous namespace outside of the compilation unit. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions).

Depending on your use-case alternatives may be:

- Use [event listeners](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#extending-googletest-by-handling-test-events) to replace the standard output.
- Pipe the output through a script that modifies the output.
- Have Google Test generate an XML or JSON report and generate output based on the XML/JSON report.

Comment: Or create PR in the googletest repository, making this function publicly available.

Comment: @wl2776 that is not necessary because you can get the same result with the standard _event listeners_ API. I have updated my question to include this option.

Comment: The fixed link to event listeners is https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#extending-googletest-by-handling-test-events . But this approach doesn't make colorful output as easy as it was with `ColoredPrintf`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issue when switching from gtest built from old sources to a more recent version inside NuGet package, and the trick with modifying `gtest.cc` isn't possible in this case, because there is no such file in the package distribution.
After some investigation I've finally ended with copy'n'pasted functions from `gtest.cc` (namely `GetColorAttribute`, `GetBitOffset`, `GetNewColor` and `ColoredPrintf`), which are then built as a part of my project (don't forget to add `#define GTEST_HAS_FILE_SYSTEM 1` at the beginning).
And you'll need an extra header like this one:

```
namespace testing
{
  namespace internal
  {
    // namespace {
      enum class GTestColor { kDefault, kRed, kGreen, kYellow };
    //}  // namespace

    void ColoredPrintf(GTestColor color, const char* fmt, ...);
    bool ShouldUseColor(bool stdout_is_tty);
  }
}
#define PRINTF(...)  do \
  { \
    testing::internal::ColoredPrintf(testing::internal::GTestColor::kGreen, "[          ] "); \
    testing::internal::ColoredPrintf(testing::internal::GTestColor::kYellow, __VA_ARGS__); \
  } while(0)
```

`static` modifier should also be removed from `ColoredPrintf` definition. The rest of code can be used as is, and it works as expected:
[image: Custom colored output]

Hopefully this issue will be properly resolved in the context of [FR#4185](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/4185)  :)