# Suppress output from google test assertions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a couple of tests that test interpolations of continuous functions, and when my implementation fails for some reason I get *lots* of output like the following from my Google test suite:

```
/home/tlycken/exjobb/Code/alpha-orbit-follower/test/interpolation/interpolation-tests.cpp:71: Failure
The difference between this->test_function_y_deriv(x,y) and this->getInterpObjectPtr()->evaluateAt(x,y,0,1) is 1.5395837072062037, which exceeds tol, where
this->test_function_y_deriv(x,y) evaluates to -1.5395837072062037,
this->getInterpObjectPtr()->evaluateAt(x,y,0,1) evaluates to 0, and
tol evaluates to 0.01.
```

Since I basically loop over the interpolated interval and test with `ASSERT_NEAR()` in a lot of places, I'm not surprised, but it would be nice to suppress the details of each error message, and just see the pass/fail status of the test case in the report. If a test fails, and I don't understand why, I can reenable the output and look closer.

However, I can't find any information on how to suppress that kind of output. Perhaps my Google-fu is inadequate...

Is there a command line flag, or some other means, to suppress the output from individual `ASSERT*` calls, and just show the final test report?

**Code sample:**

As this seems to be difficult to reproduce, this is the code I'm running. In my test fixture, I have the following method:

```
void on_interpolated_grid(std::function<void(double)> f) {
    double dxp = dx / 10;
    double xmax = xmin + (N - 1) * dx;

    for (double xp = xmin + 2 * dx; xp < xmax - 2 * dx; xp += dxp) {
        f(xp);
    }
}
```

and the test is defined like this:

```
TYPED_TEST(Interp1D_F, SecondOrderDerivative) {
    Interp1D itp(this->N, this->x, this->f);

    this->on_interpolated_grid([itp](double x) -> void {
        ASSERT_NEAR(-sin(x), itp.evaluateAt(x, 2), 1e-3);
    });
}
```

The members `N`, `x` and `f` on the test fixture are just parameters for initialization of the interpolation object.

I also tried to wrap the call to `on_interpolated_grid` in `ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURES`, but it didn't help.

Comment: @nouney: No; that only lets me add to the output, or to change how my own types are presented, but not *disable* certain types of output. Try it yourself: See if you can make a test containing `ASSERT_NEAR(3.5, 3.0, 0.1);` fail without outputting the details on the fact that the difference between 3.5 and 3.0 is greater than 0.1 - I just want to see the test fail in the summary.

Comment: Do you really use ASSERT_NEAR or EXPECT_NEAR? ASSERT_NEAR should fail the test at the first failure?

Comment: isn't it easier to filter the output to only display the first line for each result (or whatever you prefer) ? That would also give you the added advantage not to have to re-run the tests to see the details (just disable the filter).

Comment: @Philipp: I'm using `ASSERT_NEAR`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: How do I do that?

Comment: @TomasLycken : depending on how fancy you want to get, a simple [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) (or similar) should do the trick.

Comment: @TomasLycken: with 
TEST(MyTest, ManyAsserts)
{
 for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
 {
  ASSERT_NEAR(3.0,3.5,0.1);
 }
 
}
I only get one message and not 100. Maybe I didn't understand your problem correctly - do you have many different tests failing or one test failing with many messages?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: If I'd use grep to filter the test results, I'd loose all the color highlights from GTest, right? At least I don't know any way to preserve it. And that would really be a reduction  in readability of the summary.

Comment: @Philipp: Please see the updated question for an excerpt of my code. Could the fact that each assertion is inside its own method call be the problem?

Comment: @TomasLycken: Thanks, that definitely clarified the question! Please see my reply and let me know if that's an appropriate solution!

Comment: I just received a downvote on this question, but I can't really see why. If I did something bad, maybe a comment to let me know would be a nice idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem results from the fact that `ASSERT_NEAR` behaves more like `EXPECT_NEAR` in this case.

The reason for this behavior is that **Google Test uses `return` but no exceptions in `ASSERT_*`**. See [their FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Why_aren%27t_Google_Test_assertions_implemented_using_excepti) for why they do this (in short: it allows to run tests even with exceptions disabled but has other advantages in some cases like `ASSERT` in `try`-blocks.

The downside of this approach is exactly what you have here: `ASSERT_` does not propagate fatal failures if used in subfunctions (or a lambda as in your case). The GTest Advanced topics page has [a section regarding this problem](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Propagating_Fatal_Failures). With `HasFatalFailure()` your situation can be solved with a modified lambda method:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gtest/gtest-typed-test.h"
#include <functional>

void on_interpolated_grid(std::function<void(double)> f) {
    ///ADDED a few values here
    double dxp = 1.0 / 10.0;
    double xmin = 0.1;
    double dx = 0.1;
    int N = 100;
    double xmax = xmin + (N - 1) * dx;

    for (double xp = xmin + 2 * dx; xp < xmax - 2 * dx; xp += dxp) {
        f(xp);
    }
}



TEST(Interp1D_F, SecondOrderDerivative) {
    ///REMOVED. Not required for sample
    //Interp1D itp(this->N, this->x, this->f);

    on_interpolated_grid([](double x) -> void {
        ///ADDED:
        //Only check for further failures if no previous fatal failure ocurred
        if (!this->HasFatalFailure())
            ASSERT_NEAR(-sin(x),0 , 1e-3);

    });
}
```

To see the full test output (if desired), you just remove the added line.

Comment: I had to change the call to `this->HasFatalFailure()` (i.e. add `this->`) in order to avoid `error: there are no arguments to ‘HasFatalFailure’ that depend on a template parameter` when compiling, but after adding that (and removing `ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURES`) it works just as I want it. Thanks!

Comment: good point, I have added the `this->` to the answer. Not sure if this is due to different compilers (GCC usually needs `this->` when VS doesn't) or if it is because you are using `TYPED_TEST` which might result in a template while `TEST` does not. But with `this->` it should be safe in any case!

Comment: Yeah, it might be a compiler issue - I'm using GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I asked similar question ([Reducing output of gtest, to look similar to output of cxxtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553669/reducing-output-of-gtest-to-look-similar-to-output-of-cxxtest)).

If you want to fully suppress the output, you can use `::testing::EmptyTestEventListener`. For anything fancy, you have to implement custom listener (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572488/476681)).

You can even add an option in `main()` to change the listener depending on program parameters.

You said that you want colorful output. googletest's maintainers added functions to print text in color. I know you shouldn't, but if you declare those functions, you will get access to them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems google test AssertionResult are printed to standard output by design. No built-in command line option to disable specific parts of the that output either.

If tweaking google test itself is an option, then the easiest would probably be to add a condition around the `PrintTestPartResult` call in `PrettyUnitTestResultPrinter::OnTestPartResult`, and similarly with calls to `PrintFullTestCommentIfPresent` in `OnTestEnd`/`PrintFailedTests`. In that case, your own option to control verbosity could be included in `ParseGoogleTestFlagsOnlyImpl` and `kColorEncodedHelpMessage`.

Otherwise (i.e. if recompiling google test is not an option), it is possible to write a `TestEventListener` replacement to the default `PrettyUnitResultPrinter` (possibly inspired from `PrettyUnitResultPrinter` itself), as documented in [google test samples](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/samples/sample9_unittest.cc).