# How to set up googletest wtih meson?

Tags: linux, clang, googletest, ninja, meson-build

I have a git repository with some test code in C++ and I want to use [Googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest/) to write some tests. I used `git submodule` to get it as part of the above repository. I want to use [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) as the build engine. So far, so good.

However, I cannot fathom how to get meson to build and link my tests with the googletest submodule… Should I use a wrap? An external dependency? what?

Note that [meson supports dependencies on packaged versions of gtest/gmock](https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#gtest-and-gmock) but this is not what I want since the developers of gtest/gmock recommend against it. Plus, I want bleeding edge 'cause I am crazy⸮

Furthermore, I do not think ninja plays a role here but I mentioned that I use it just in case.

Comment: Sounds about right, what is the linker error?

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Err … An error between keyboard and floor. I was using [this clever hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572488/232794) which is not really needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried using [the wrap for gtest](https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/gtest) with

```
gtest_proj = subproject('gtest')
gtest_dep = gtest_proj.get_variable('gtest_dep')
gmock_dep = gtest_proj.get_variable('gmock_dep')
```

in `meson.build`. This builds a local copies of googletest which can then be used like so:

```
tests_src = [
  'tests/gtest-all.cpp',
  'tests/test_MyClass.cpp',
]  
e = executable(
  'gtest-all',
  tests_src,
  dependencies : [
    gtest_dep,
    gmock_dep],
  link_with : libshield,
)    
test('gtest tests', e)
```

Note that `libshield` is a shared library created from my (toy) code so I can link to it.

Answer (score 10):

If you would like to use a project that is not meson project you need to find that project in wrapDB:

```
meson wrap search gtest
```

If that command gives you name of the wrap then you need to install it to your project:

```
mkdir -p subprojects
meson wrap install gtest
```

Then you should reconfigure your project and meson will download that project for you:

```
meson --reconfigure path/to/build/dir
```

Additional information you can find in documentation of [wrap tool](https://mesonbuild.com/Using-wraptool.html).

*--reconfigure* - supported since [0.49.0](https://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html#update-subprojects)

Comment: meson gives me an error: `unrecognized arguments: --reconfigure`. It then does on to print a list of possible arguments. None of them appear to be close to reconfigure

Comment: @Hemil, what is your version of meson?

Comment: @Hemil, it supported since **0.49.0**

Comment: The one i got from synaptic was 0.45.1 @Umed

Comment: Downloading the latest one from github :) I got it to work anyway. Thanks