# The executable test file is not running the tests

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I have created a project:

```
// func.h :
#ifndef FUNCS_H_
#define FUNCS_H_

int addInts(int i, int j);

#endif /* FUNCS_H_ */
```

---

```
// func.cpp
#include "func.h"

int addInts(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}
```

---

```
// main.cpp
#include "func.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << addInts(5, 7) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
//makefile
OBJS := \
    main.o \
    func.o

CXX := g++

CXX_FLAGS := -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++11

all: main_prj

main_prj: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) -lm -o main

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) $*.cpp -o $*.o

clean:
    rm -f main $(OBJS)
```

And I created also a test (boost test) for that function:

```
// test/main_test.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE main_test
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

//____________________________________________________________________________//


// FIXTURES ...

//____________________________________________________________________________//
```

---

```
// test/addInts/addInts_test.cpp
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "../../func.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(addInts_5_7) {
    int addInts_5_7 = 5 + 7;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(addInts_5_7, addInts(5, 7));
}
```

---

```
// test/makefile
OBJS_TEST := \
    main_test.o \
    addInts/addInts_test.o \
    ../func.o

CXX_TEST := g++

CXX_FLAGS_TEST := -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++11

all_test: main_test_prj

main_test_prj: $(OBJS_TEST)
    $(CXX_TEST) $(OBJS_TEST) -lm -o main_test

-include $(OBJS_TEST:.o=.d)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX_TEST) -c $(CXX_FLAGS_TEST) $*.cpp -o $*.o

clean_test:
    rm -f main_test $(OBJS_TEST)
```

---

Now, the make commands work, so they clean all the created files, or create the o files and the executables. When I run the main file, the output is correct: 12 ; but when I run the main_test file, the output is a little strange:

```
Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected
```

I would expect the output with running tests and OK/KO, or pass/not pass... I cannot figure what am I doing wrong. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one test.

The output says that one test was run, and that no errors were found.

This output appears to be as [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html).

**There is no problem here.**

<sub>*Though, sadly, [the documentation on how to change this output](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/results-report.html) is rather lacking…*</sub>

Comment: You are right. did not pay attention, but I added more tests and it seems to output the same thing, except the number of tests and if one fails, then the error is printed, where and what; but is there a way to see the "beautiful" output with each test name and ok/ko ?

Comment: ...nevermind, it is not important to have the OKs... :)

Comment: @sop If you want some specific kind of output, you're going to have to tell us what it is. Though, as pointed out at the bottom of my answer, I don't think I could help you with that anyway. :) The Boost mailing lists may be of more help.

Comment: Yes, you did :) I was thinking about something like the output of googletest (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923903/printing-additional-output-in-google-test) for seeing an example), but the logging to xml is ok too